# Search Array for Longest String that is a Prefix of Search String

Tags: swift, string, search, startswith

I'm a new Swift developer.  I'm using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.2.

I would like to search an array for a single result that has the most characters compared to my search string.  To be more specific, I need the longest string from my array which is a prefix of the search string.

For example, if my array is:

```
let array = ["1", "13", "1410", "1649", "1670"]
```

and my search string is:

```
let searchString = "16493884777"
```

I would like the result to be `"1649"`.

I can't find another SO question that has a swift solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the entry which has the most characters in common with the search string, or for the entry with the longest common prefix? In other words: would `xxx16493884777` qualify as best result or not?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  The longest common prefix is what I need.  The array will contain unique strings.  xxx16493884777 would not qualify as the best result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just iterate over the prefix array from the end (assuming the prefix array is sorted) and return immediately if you hit a match since that prefix will be guaranteed to be the longest since another matching prefix of the same length cannot exist:

```
import Foundation

func longestMatchingPrefix(_ prefixArray: [String], _ searchString: String) -> String {
    for p in prefixArray.reversed() {
        if searchString.hasPrefix(p) {
           return p
        }
    }
    return "No matching prefix found"
}

print(longestMatchingPrefix(["1", "13", "1410", "1649", "1670"], "16493884777"))
```

**Output:**

```
1649
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is an elegant solution.  Am testing with my larger array, but it works well in the playground.

Comment: `longestMatchingPrefix(["1", "13", "1410", "1649", "1670"], "164")` returns "1" and not  "1649" – is that the intended result?

Comment: Yes.  That would be correct.  Because the searchString 164 does not have the 9, I would not want to use that result.  Likewise, if I search "1200", I would expect to get back "1".

Comment: @TMLynch: So you are not looking for the string with the longest common prefix, but for the longest string which is a prefix of the search string? Perhaps you should clarify your question (for the sake of future readers of this Q&A).

Comment: I guess that is the best way to describe it.  As you can see, I struggled with the logic behind it.  Thank you, I will clarify the question.

Comment: Note that this solution can be simplified to `prefixArray.reversed().first(where: searchString.hasPrefix)`